# Angular-Flexslider with json object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using Angular-Flexslider on my App and I need it to display images from a json object.

Angular-flexslider includes a directive flex-slider which acts like ng-repeat so this works

```
<flex-slider slide="s in mySlides">
    <li>
        <img ng-src="{{s}}">
    </li>
</flex-slider>
```

However I need it to get images from on object not an array, and this doesn't work.

```
<flex-slider slide="(key, s) in mySlidesObj">
    <li>
        <img ng-src="{{s.slide}}">
    </li>
</flex-slider>
```

Is there anyway I can get this to work?

The Controller just has data:

```
app.controller('BasicSliderCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.mySlides = [
        'http://images.mydomain.com/General-3-320x320.jpg',
        'http://images.mydomain.com/Jared-video-320x320.jpg'
    ];

    $scope.mySlidesObj = {
      "1001" : {
        "slide" : "http://images.mydomain.com/img1.jpg"
      },      
      "1002" : {
        "slide" : "http://images.mydomain.com/ig2.jpg"
      },          
      "1003" : {
        "slide" : "http://images.mydomain.com/img3.jpg"
      },          
      "1004" : {
        "slide" : "http://images.mydomain.com/ig4.jpg"
      },

    }
});
```

Comment: What does your controller look like?

Comment: The controller just has data. I need to tie it to a database, but for the moment I'm just trying to figure out how to get this to work with on object, other than an array. I edited my post with a snippet of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glancing at the source code it looks like iterating over objects isn't supported.

Your best option is probably to manually turn your object into an array.

For example:

```
$scope.mySlides = Object.keys($scope.mySlidesObj).map(function(slideObj) {
  return $scope.mySlidesObj[slideObj].slide;
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/fJ8IrPAt0cInvzD6fwdy?p=preview